# TFS 2012 Identity Sync AD Error

Tags: active-directory, team-foundation-server

I have a newly installed TFS 2012 server set up and I am having problems with the synchronisation of Windows Groups (AD Groups).

My domain is called DOMAINA and my service account for TFSAgentJob is DOMAINA\TFS-Service. I have verified with dsquery that the service account can access the Active Directory. The Active Directory Server is Windows Active Directory Server 2000

When I add a domain user to a project collection then the user recieve the proper permissions, but when I add a domain group that the user is a member of then the permissions are not set. When I manage the group from the web interface I can see that no users has been synchronized to this group.

I have enabled logging of the TFSJobAgent as described in http://blog.hinshelwood.com/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/ and here is an excerpt of the log: http://pastebin.com/NP26Vrmq

The error that is thrown is:
"Exception Message: The server does not support the requested critical extension."

I have also removed the BUILTIN\Administrators group, but this did not happen.

I have run out of troubleshooting options, can anyone help me identify the error?

What is the "requested critical extension" that the server doesn't support?

Comment: What is the Domain/Forest funtional level of your Windows 2000 AD domain? Is it `mixed mode` or `native`?

Comment: It is running in native.